# how to send a message to email with php

Tags: php

I'm trying to send a message to the email a user provides in the contact form. The problem is the message never gets sent, but I always arrive at a blank page where my php code is located. Nothing warns me of any error in my code. Can anyone explain why this is happening and offer a solution to the problem?

```
      <form action="site.php" method="POST">
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form"
        name="email"
        placeholder="Your email address"
      />
      <button class="submit" type="submit">Join Waitlist</button>
    </form>
```

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $mailTo = $_POST["email"];
    $mailFrom = "Dumele";
    $message = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1lpj2XnKW4HT_qHFfGwpUxcvzPmK2USZ0MGSDP0XCqfg/edit";
    $subject = "Welcome to Dumele";
    
    $txt = "Thank you for your interest in Dumele. We're glad to have 
    you join our network and mission to enhance the technological 
    innovation of our African diaspora. Below is a link to a survey 
    we would like you to answer so we can better assist you.\n\n".message;

    $headers = "From: ".mailFrom;

        (mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers));
        header("Location: index.php?mailsend");
    
}
```

?>

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "a blank page where my php code is located"?  Are you seeing PHP code in your browser?

Comment: You need `name="submit"` in your submit button otherwise the first `if` in the PHP will never be true.

Comment: @David no I don't see any php code. the browser just takes me to the separate file where my php code is located once I click the submit button.

Comment: Also your mail from field needs to include a proper email address. Please find some examples of the usage of mail() and study them carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure you enabled error reporting. You can check another Stackoverflow question and it's answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) about it.

As I see in your code you have syntax errors. You didn't place `$` sign before variable names. For example you typed `$headers = "From: ".mailFrom;` instead of `$headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;` Let's fix it:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $mailTo = $_POST["email"];
    $mailFrom = "Dumele";
    $message = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1lpj2XnKW4HT_qHFfGwpUxcvzPmK2USZ0MGSDP0XCqfg/edit";
    $subject = "Welcome to Dumele";
    
    $txt = "Thank you for your interest in Dumele. We're glad to have 
    you join our network and mission to enhance the technological 
    innovation of our African diaspora. Below is a link to a survey 
    we would like you to answer so we can better assist you.\n\n".$message;

    $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;

        (mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers));
        header("Location: index.php?mailsend");
    
}
```

Now with the `mail()` function of PHP; some servers disables `mail()` function for security purposes. If so; you can use SMTP to securely send your emails. To use SMTP in PHP of course you need additional processes but some free software packages and libraries like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or [SwiftMailer](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer) can help you about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is looking for a form value with the name "submit":

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
```

But there's no form element in the HTML with that name.  So this will always be `false`.  Give your submit button that name:

```
<button class="submit" type="submit" name="submit">Join Waitlist</button>
```

It shouldn't necessarily need a *value*, it would just default to an empty string.  But it needs a *name* in order for the browser to send anything at all with that key.

---

As an aside, your mail server *may* reject the message since this is not really an email address:

```
$mailFrom = "Dumele";
```

---

For completeness... It looks like your PHP variables are also syntactically incorrect.  Variable names need to begin with a `$`.  For example, this:

```
$headers = "From: ".mailFrom;
```

Should be this:

```
$headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
```

The same error would need to be corrected anywhere you're mis-using variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Use value attribute in button tag. You are testing
if(isset($_post['submit']))

But what is submit? You should use value attribute and give a value submit i.e. Submit

Comment: if your question is "How to send an email using PHP", then, you can either use the PHP mail function mail() or you can use PHPMailer library.